# Is there a Regex expression for phone number validation?

Tags: c#

I'm setting up a new website, and want to validate user input phone number. What Regex expression do I need to use to get the format 04xx xxx xxx? There needs to be a space between the fifth and ninth character.

I have tried using this expression: `^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$`.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    namespace InspiringMagazines.Models
    {
        public class Customer
        {
                public int customerID { get; set; }
                [Display(Name = "GivenName")]
                [MinLength(2), StringLength(20), Required(ErrorMessage =                                                         
    @"The Given Name is required.")]
                [RegularExpression(@"[0-9][a-z'-]{3,20}")]
                public string firstName { get; set; }
                [Display(Name = "FamilyName")]
                [MinLength(2), StringLength(20), Required(ErrorMessage =         
    @"The Family Name is required.")]
                [RegularExpression(@"[0-9][a-z'-]{3,20}")]
                public string lastName { get; set; }
                [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
                public string dateOfBirth { get; set; }
                public string emailAddress { get; set; }
                [MinLength(12), StringLength(12), Required(ErrorMessage =         
    @"The Phone Number is required.")]

                public string mobileNumber { get; set; }
                public string postalCode { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Expected result is to have phone numbers not in the format of 04xx xxx xxx to show an error message. The actual result right now is all the numbers are being accepted.

Comment: Your expression doesn't seem to have a whole lot to do with `04xx xxx xxx`, which you could match simply with `/^04\d\d( \d{3}){2}$/`. Can you clarify your intent and show a variety of examples illustrating what you'd like to match and what you'd like to reject? Also `{0,1}` is clearer as `?` in regex.

Comment: Is your question about regular expressions or about wiring things up so that mvc doses the validating for you?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest regex in terms of comprehension would be:

```
^04\d\d \d\d\d \d\d\d$
```

But beware, this would probably let them type in Unicode numbers outside the ascii range too

To be honest, excessive validation is more irritating to users than it is helpful to you, especially when your error messages are so poor. Having some complicated requirement for input and then only telling them "the given name is required"  is bad. What if their name really is "Q"? You don't say "given name must be at least two characters" (better error message) but then my question in this is "why must a name be at least two characters?" What do you care if a person puts one character in as their name?

Likewise for phone numbers , let them type in whatever they like, any old how. Strip all the crap they typed in when you validate and check they entered 10 digits starting with 04. The error message should say "phone number should start with 04 and have 10 digits in total". Prepopulate the box with 04 to help them out, and run this on what they give you:

```
Regex.Replace(theirInput, "[^0-9]", "");
```

It strips out all the hyphens, brackets, spaces etc. Check the length of the result. The message here is: "don't require your user to type spaces in because the spaces really don't matter. You can put them in yourself in code, after you strip the user input of `(0400) 223-456` down to just numbers `0400223456`, simply using string substring

"Be tolerant of what you accept and strict of what you send" is the mantra for writing servers that talk HTTP, but it's a good thing to apply to any user input; Always aim to take as much varied junk input off the user and clean it up to meet your standards rather than forcing the user to meet it, and if you are forcing the user, definitely tell them exactly where they're going wrong. Aim for validation that feeds back instantly- don't have them submit the whole form then reject it and sent them back to one that is missing the values for its complicated double passwords fields and have them redo the captcha, or worse blank out all their input that was invalid

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this regex

```
^(04\d{2}\s\d{3}\s\d{3})$
```

Tested on [regexr](https://regexr.com/4kbv9)

Comment: Why square brackets around \s?

Comment: @CaiusJard Thank you for the comment. I removed those brackets now. Actually in the beginning I tried this using `^(04\d{2}[ ]\d{3}[ ]\d{3})$` to make it easy to recognize the white-space. I also have a doubt on when to use those square brackets.

Comment: Square brackets are used to create character classes meaning "any one of the characters inside". They also accept other character classes such as \s, effectively expanding them. They also provide a way of escaping most characters to make them lose their normal meaning (.*+ for example all become literals when inside s character class).

Answer (score 0):

For Nigerian phone numbers the following regex pattern works `[0]([7-9][0]|[8][0-1])[0-9]{8}` . Just paste it in your Regex match

Answer (score 0):

regex for nigerian phone number

without spacing

```
 /^234[0-9]{10}$/
```

with spacing

```
/^234\s[0-9]{10}$/
```